# Adding new row to DataGridView by KeyDown

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` with 4 columns (column 3 is hidden). The `DataGridView` is ready for user input when it is loaded (I added one row and set `AllowUserToAddRows=false)`. When the user press `Enter` then the next cell is focused and editable. After the third column pressing `Enter` then a new row should be inserted.

For adding the new row I have to write the already inserted data back to a `datatable` because the `DataGridView` is already databound.

When I try to access the first row in which I inserted some values it returns me always zero:

[image]

[image]

How can I access the first row? Thanks!

Code for `Datatable`:

```
 dtKasse.Columns.Add("Nummer");
 dtKasse.Columns.Add("Unternummer");
 dtKasse.Columns.Add("Betrag");
 dtKasse.Columns.Add("Datum");

 dtKasse.Rows.Add("", "", "", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
 gv_Input.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
 gv_Input.DataSource = dtKasse;

 DataGridViewCell cell = gv_Input.Rows[0].Cells[0];
 gv_Input.CurrentCell = cell;
 gv_Input.BeginEdit(true);
```

Hide third column:

```
private void gv_Input_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
    {
        gv_Input.Columns[3].Visible = false;
    }
```

Handle pressing `Enter`:

```
private void gv_Input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
    {
        int col = gv_Input.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
        int row = gv_Input.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

        if (col < 2) 
        {
            col++;
        }
        else
        {
            col = 0; 
            row++; 
        }

        if (row == gv_Input.RowCount) 
        {
            dtKasse.Clear(); 
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in gv_Input.Rows)
            {
                dtKasse.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells[0].Value, dgr.Cells[1].Value, dgr.Cells[2].Value, dgr.Cells[3].Value);
            }
            DataRow dr = dtKasse.NewRow();
            dtKasse.Rows.Add(dr);
            gv_Input.DataSource = dtKasse;
        }

        DataGridViewCell cell = gv_Input.Rows[row].Cells[col];
        gv_Input.CurrentCell = cell;
        gv_Input.BeginEdit(true);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you must understand about setting the `DataGridView.DataSource` is that:

- Changes made to the source will be reflected in the `DataGridView`.

With that in mind, consider the following:

1. Calling `dtKasse.Clear();` will clear your `DataGridView.Rows` too.
2. Adding a new row to the sourced `DataTable` for each row in the `DataGridView` will cause an infinite loop.
3. Resetting the `DataGridView.DataSource` is redundant.

**Solution**: In your `KeyDown` event, change your inner if-statement to simply add a new row to the sourced `DataTable`:

```
if (row == gv_Input.RowCount) 
{
    DataRow dr = dtKasse.NewRow();
    dtKasse.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Also, you should add `e.Handled = true` after you set the `CurrentCell` and call `BeginEdit`, otherwise you'll see undesired behavior navigating cells.